# change color of some selected text in GWT TextArea

Tags: gwt

I am trying to change the color for some of the text in my GWT Text Area.
I know the start and end of the text I want to change the color.

Now Is there any way I can change the color (apply some css) to the text in that location.

example..  This is the text in my GWT Text Area

"Hello, this is an example"

Now the words 'an example' need to be in red color.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

GWT implementation of [TextArea](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TextArea.html) is just call to DOM for a creation of
an [HTML TextArea](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp) Object. Thus, GWT object has the same limitations as
HTML object.

Try with [RichTextArea](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RichTextArea.html) that allows complex styling and formatting.

Comment: Thanks , I also need cursorPosition which is not in RichTextArea.

Comment: Are you sure? Let me check for cursor position.

Comment: yeah, cant find cursor position in RichTextArea

Comment: @junaidp `RichTextArea` doesn't provide methods to get/set the cursor position. But there are other SO questions with JSNI solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542522/how-to-get-cursor-position-or-location-from-richtextarea-in-gwt) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549739/how-to-setcursor-position-in-gwt-richtextarea).

Comment: Using this JSNI approach, Not much experience of JSNI, Should i pass richTextArea in this method instead public static native JsArrayString getSelection(Element elem) /*-{    instead of Element..                  I tried changing Element to RichTextArea when i run , it gives null error

Comment: have you tried all the possible solutions posted by @Baz in both the links? Take your time and read here about [JSNI](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html)